# differential cryptanalysis cipher for the final round

Tags: cryptanalysis, differential-analysis

I have a problem to find the sub-key.

The  system is…

> For each round, we make the following stage:
>
> 1. We add the round key $K_i$.
> 2. Substitution : we have 8 blocks of 4 bits, and an S-box takes each block.
>
>    S = [7,3,6,1,13,9,10,11,2,12,0,4,5,15,8,14]
> 3. Permutation : circular shift of 2 to the right.

I choose the differential $\Delta(1 \implies 4)$ because after the permutation the differential trail is $\Delta(1 \implies 4 \implies 1)$.
I coded in C, the algorithm to find the $K_5$, the sub key after 5 rounds.

`plainText[m]` is a random message and `plainText[m+1]` is `plainText[m] ^ 1`(difference).

```
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0001
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
| S1 | | S2 | | S3 | | S4 | | S5 | | S6 | | S7 | | S8 |
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0100
                                                    \
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0001
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
| S1 | | S2 | | S3 | | S4 | | S5 | | S6 | | S7 | | S8 |
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
 0000   0000  0000    0000   0000   0000   0000   0100
```

I tested the function of encryption and decryption, it operates normally.
The problem is that I get a uniform array, because when I decrypted message, the differential trail is good for all the keys while normally this should not always be the case for any key for a message.

For example:

```
plaintText[i]=7584 and plaintText[i+1]=7585(7584 XOR 1).
```

In my code, for `key=0,u=69b900ca` and `up=645100ca` and `tmp=2b131dd4` so `beta=4`. For `key=1,u=69b900ca` and `up=645100cb` and `beta=4`. The problem is that for any key, I get the same beta.

Answer (score 4):

> **Remark:** The round function of your toy cipher is the following.
>
> ```
>        |
> K ---> + 
>        |
>     -------
>     |  S  |
>     -------
>        |
>       >> 2
>        |
> ```
>
> Hence in the last round, the shift and S-box are useless (because invertible hence do not add security) which is why **in a SPN scheme the key addition at the end is preferred.**

---

I did a quick check your S-box differentials:

```
    |   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  0 |  16                                                             
  1 |       2           6       2   2           2               2     
  2 |       4   6                   2   2                   2         
  3 |               2       2   6   2               2   2             
  4 |               2               2   2       8       2             
  5 |                                       2       2   2   4   6     
  6 |           2           2           4       2   4       2         
  7 |       2           2                   2           6           4 
  8 |           2           6   4       2                           2 
  9 |       4   4   2   2                           2   2             
 10 |                   4   2       6                       2       2 
 11 |       2       8       2                   2               2     
 12 |           2           2                   2       2       2   6 
 13 |       2                   2       4   2       4           2     
 14 |               2               2   2                   6   2   2 
 15 |                   2       2          10       2                 
0011 => 0110 : 6 / 16
0010 => 0010 : 6 / 16
0101 => 1110 : 6 / 16
0001 => 0100 : 6 / 16
0100 => 1010 : 8 / 16
1100 => 1111 : 6 / 16
0111 => 1100 : 6 / 16
1010 => 0111 : 6 / 16
1011 => 0011 : 8 / 16
1110 => 1101 : 6 / 16
1111 => 1001 : 10 / 16
1000 => 0101 : 6 / 16
```

Hence the chosen one $\Delta(0001 \implies 0100)$ holds with a probability of $6/16$.
However you forgot that you work with a 32bits block cipher:
Meaning that with your chosen difference ($1$), will switch of to the next S-box after each round :

```
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0001
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
| S1 | | S2 | | S3 | | S4 | | S5 | | S6 | | S7 | | S8 |
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0100
                                                   \
                                                    \     ROUND 1
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0001
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
| S1 | | S2 | | S3 | | S4 | | S5 | | S6 | | S7 | | S8 |
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0100
                                                   \
                                                    \     ROUND 2
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0001
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
| S1 | | S2 | | S3 | | S4 | | S5 | | S6 | | S7 | | S8 |
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0100
                                                   \
                                                    \     ROUND 3
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0001
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
| S1 | | S2 | | S3 | | S4 | | S5 | | S6 | | S7 | | S8 |
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0100
 ||||   ||||   ||||   ||||   ||||   ||||   ||||   ||||
 0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   ????
 \                                                \\\\
 \\                                                \\\  ROUND 4
 ??00   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   0000   00?? <-This is where you attack

------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
| S1 | | S2 | | S3 | | S4 | | S5 | | S6 | | S7 | | S8 |
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
 ????   ????   ????   ????   ????   ????   ????   ????  Round 5
```

It is also note worthy that this differential holds with a probability of $3^4/8^4 = 81/4096 \approx 2\%$.

---

*I did the attack when the key addition is at the end. I'm trying to make it works when the key addition is at the begining. WIP*

Comment: thanks for your help, I had ignored a circular shift in the computation of the output of sbox. But the output should not be like this:                                                                                             0001   0000   0000   
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ 
| S1 | | S2 | | S3 | | 
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ 
 0010   0000   0000                      
 0000   1000   0000   
Because we shift to the right?

Comment: Oups yes, I don't know why, I read to the left... But you got the idea. :)

Comment: I modified my code, but nevertheless I always have the problem of the result because when I decrypt of a round,i obtain well the characteristic but for 16 keys. For example: decrypt (ciphertext [m], 0) =1(characteristic), decrypt (ciphertext [m+1], 1)= 1... I do not understand why for 16 keys, I obtain the same thing

Comment: Well I guess that is a problem with your code. But unfortunately I can't see where. I would strongly advise you to check all your functions one by one. And by check I mean to tests most of possible inputs.

Comment: I check my encryption and decryption function is working correctly. I think cel can come to my choice of plaintText that I randomly selects and my second plaintText plaintext = ^ 1.